# Bootstrap Select style and search not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) with the search functionality. I can not seem to get it to work, I installed it using npm install bootstrap-select which installs fine @1.12.4 My code for the div and select is:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select class="selectpicker" id="sel" name="manufacturer" onchange="man()" data-live-search="true">
  <option selected>Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="cisco">Cisco</option>
  <option value="netgear">NetGear</option>                             
  <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Why is it not working? What did I miss type?

Comment: Did you remember to actually include the plugin?

Comment: I get this after I include it in my index file `ome/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js:157
    _set: $.valHooks.select.set
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined`

Comment: @ObsidianAge forgot to tag you in previous comment reply

Comment: I should add when I include the CDN CSS and JS link/script it just makes the selects disappear. They don't show up in the browser at all.

Comment: Can you also add your js part

Comment: @Naga2Raja What JS part? Do you have to do custom setup for this package? I figured it was install then require and it should work when used. The only js I have for this is `var jQuery = require("jquery");
var bootstrapSelect = require("bootstrap-select");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you need to do

```js
$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Country</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-country" data-live-search="true">
                <option data-tokens="china">China</option>
                <option data-tokens="malayasia">Malayasia</option>
                <option data-tokens="singapore">Singapore</option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: I tried this and while the code snippet works I can only get the style to sorta work and the drop-down fails fully even when I use to select you have directly.

Comment: I added those includes to the header file so load order should not be the issue.

Comment: @JoshKirby order doesn't matter, but as a try, i request you to put it in the same order as the above.. Basically calling the js before using it.

Comment: I did I added all JS to the header file. Copy and paste of yours fails. The function you posted comes at the top of my footer with the other includes in the header.

Comment: Okay I played around with order and got them to sorta work. The only issue now is they are greyed out like they should be disabled but they are not disabled

Comment: How can I put `data-live-search` attribute in razor syntax?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because you haven't added the dependency java script file for using bootstrap-select. Mostly  Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component.

You can try including the following script and execute.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have bootstrap included already, I am using the JS part in other areas of my project.

Comment: I hope you had not missed out jquery.min.js